# Inconsistent title for posts

Tags: title, seo

I remember, I had edited some part of my theme for optimizing the title values. Currently in google I see [this](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=site%3Awww.javaexperience.com&btnG=Search#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&ei=X7YPUpb0D4WPrQeu74D4AQ&fp=f0f325d06c6efeb0&hl=en&q=site%3awww.javaexperience.com&sa=N&safe=off&start=10).

Whereas when I open a post, the site name is not appended to the post title.

I looked at the `header.php` of my theme and found the following line:

```
<title><?php seotitles(); ?></title>
```

I am using "All in one SEO" plugin and have set the title and description of each post manually and when I do so, I don't append the site name in the post name.

How can I bring what I see in google and what the user sees in sync with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually nothing you can do about this. Google changed their algorithm a few months ago where they will sometimes determine the title in their results if they feel it's a better fit.

I noticed this when working on the SEO for the last company I worked for. When searching "channel letters detroit" the results gave "Channel Letters - Detroit Sign Company SIGNARAMA Troy" for http://michigansignshops.com/products/outdoor-signs/channel-letters/, while the page title is "Detroit Channel Letters, Fast Fabrication & Cost Effective | SIGNARAMA".

Joost de Valk from Yoast (Author of WordPress SEO, which is very similar to All in one SEO)  actually explains a little more of this in [Why Google won't display the right page title](http://yoast.com/google-page-title/).

Answer (score 0):

Ian Stewart's tutorial shows an understandable and SEO-friendly `<title>`, you can follow

```
<title><?php
    if ( is_single() ) { single_post_title(); print ' - '; bloginfo('name'); }
    elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); print ' - '; bloginfo('description'); get_page_number(); }
    elseif ( is_page() ) { single_post_title(''); }
    elseif ( is_search() ) { bloginfo('name'); print ' - Search results for ' . esc_html($s); get_page_number(); }
    elseif ( is_404() ) { bloginfo('name'); print ' - Not Found'; }
    else { bloginfo('name'); wp_title('-'); get_page_number(); }
?></title>
```

It'll put a title into your post page title like:

```
GET and POST requests - Java Experience
```

I hope that'll work for you. But don't know what are the settings you need to change into the "All in one SEO" settings. Good Luck!